# Javascript classList.add is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem with classList.add javascript function.
I am trying to add "active" class onto elements and apply css style for those active classes. However, it doesn't seem to work and I am having hard time with it.
Could anyone help me with this issue?
Below is the current  part from my HTML file and css part that corresponds to this javascript.

Part:

```html
<script>
    function debounce(func, wait = 20, immediate = true) {
      var timeout;
      return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
          timeout = null;
          if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
      };
    }

    const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

    function checkSlide(e) {
      sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
        const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - sliderImage.height / 2; 
        const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.height;
        const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
        const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;

        if(isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
          sliderImage.classList.add('active');
        } else {
          sliderImage.classList.remove('active');
        }
      })
    }


    window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(checkSlide));

  </script>
```

CSS part that corresponds to above javascript:

```css
.slide-in {
 opacity: 0;
 transition:all .5s;
}

.align-left {
 float: left;
 /*margin-right: 20px;*/
}

.align-right {
 float: right;
 /*margin-right: 20px;*/
}

.align-left.slide-in {
 transform:translateX(-30%) scale(0.95);
}

.align-right.slide-in {
 transform:translateX(30%) scale(0.95);
}

.slide-in.active {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
}
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: which browser and version are you using?

Comment: You're tagging this with jQuery, but you don't seem to be using it anywhere. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Could you post relevant `html` too?

Comment: Add a fiddle with your html ,css and javascript code

Comment: make sure your condition `if(isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast)` is true

Comment: @GraveyardQueen I am using google chrome as the browser and I believe it is the latest verision

Comment: What behavior do you expect, and what behavior do you get? What do you see when you use the style inspector? What happens when you trace through your code in the debugger? Is the `classList.add` line being reached? What is the point of providing non-working snippets in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the classList functionality instead i have made a few changes in the code as shown below,

```
<script>
function debounce(func, wait , immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

const sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

function checkSlide(e) {
  sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
    const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - (sliderImage.clientHeight / 2); 
    const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.clientHeight;
    const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
    const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;

    if(isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
      sliderImage.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      sliderImage.classList.remove('active');
    }
  })
}
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {checkSlide();}, 20,true);
window.addEventListener("scroll", myEfficientFn);
</script>
```

- I had placed the `<script>` tag inside the `<body>` tag .
- In the checkSlide function i have replace the `height` property usage by the `clientHeight`
- And finally i have returned the debounce function as seen in the last line of the code ,instead of calling the function because when the code was like this `window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(checkSlide));` the debounce function got called on load of the window the call of the function was used.When we use the code `window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){return debounce(checkSlide);});` the function gets assigned to that event and gets called every time that event happens.

Comment: If you're going to fix his code, why not replace `add` and `remove` with just `toggle`?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the design of the `debounce`. It is **supposed** to return a function--one that debounces the function passed in, which is also why specifying `debounce(checkSlide)` is **correct**.

Comment: yes you are right ,i have used the debounce as shown above